# Are there mantras specifically for Yoga Narasimha?

Tags: vishnu, mantras, narasimha

I am looking for dhyana mantras (or any mantra for that matter) of Lord **Yoga Narasimha** which may describe his posture or his calm nature etc..

**Yoga Narasimha** is the form of Narasimha in which he can seen in a meditative state. This form showcases that Narasimha is not always angry.

I am not looking for mantras of Ugra Narasimha, I am trying to read about Shanta/Soumya Narasimha.

Any shlokas with translation/source are much appreciated.
Look how beautiful and Graceful the lord is !!!

Can't believe there isn't a special shlokam for him.

[image]
I have tried to find such mantras/shlokas/stotras for past several years, since I last went to Sholingur several years back.